# WebSocket connection to 'ws://127.0.0.1:5000/socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=websocket&sid=wBX-4EpWW6-y-DfFAAAC' failed:

Tags: javascript, python, socket.io

Im trying to send a "refresh message" from a Flask python app to the html.

I did this:

```
def alert(previous_date, date, archivo):
    with app.app_context():
        if previous_date!= date:
            print(f"Alert")
            socketio.emit('refresh_page')  
            return redirect(app.config['FLASK_APP_URL'])
```

---

app = Flask(**name**)

socketio = SocketIO(app)

app.config['FLASK_APP_URL'] = 'http://127.0.0.1:5000'

---

Javascript:

```
    var socket = io.connect('http://' + document.domain + ':' + location.port);

    // listen 'refresh_page' sent by server
    socket.on('refresh_page', function() {
        // Reload
        location.reload();
    });
```

[image]

Whats the problem in here?

Comment: Can you post a minimal, reproducible example of the python and javascript for this, a lot of different issues could be causing such errors and it's hard to narrow down without a full case.

Comment: Hey @35308 i don't know how could i do that :/

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example, I've had the same issue before and it ended up being something with how I loaded socketio in my html page (or maybe some CORS restriction)

Comment: @35308 if i add this: socketio.run(app, host='127.0.0.1', port=5000, debug=True) the error is gone but the app is working strange

Comment: Just for information, why you do a flask redirect and also a JavaScript Page reload, looks redundant. Also Post your full python and js Code, so that we can see, whats going on

Comment: Hey y @Christoph If i get some event on my Python app i want to refresh the html page by sending a message from Flask to the HTML. The action is to reload the page itself

Comment: OK but why did u a redirect after emit, this would also act like an refresh.

Comment: But anyway your js Code could not connect to websocket serverside

Comment: @Christoph im kinda lost right now. Is it possible for you to show me some code?

Comment: You should Post your whole Code otherwise we could Not help

Comment: Follow this tutorial https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/easy-websockets-with-flask-and-gevent